# Fastest way to compute least-squares with relatively sparse matrix (0.4% of data)

Tags: numpy, optimization, pytorch, scipy, least-squares

**Context:** I solve the equation `A_des.x = b` where I find `x` through a least-squares method. I have to do this operation several thousands of time. `A_des` changes between each iteration but remains sparse (always around 4% of actual data in the matrix).

**Problem:** `A_des` is large (`(28106, 1185)`), and solving the linear systems takes approximately 1 second. I need to do this operation 300000 times.

**Question:** Would you have leads on what could speed-up this process ?

**What I tried:** I coded my function both on GPU and CPU. I use `pytorch` for the GPU computations, but the speed-up is inconsistent. I can not parallelize my function because the solver functions are usually already threaded. I have tried using several solver functions on CPU: `np.linalg.solve`, `np.linalg.lstsq`, `scipy.linalg.solve`, `scipy.optimize.least_squares`, `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr` (with pre-emptively converting `A_des` with `scipy.sparse.coo_array(A_des)`).

**Best method I found:** The best compromise I found was using `np.linalg.solve`, I just have to do by hand some matrix manipulation. For example, solving the system with a least-square function would be: `x = np.linalg.lstsq(A_des, b)` while with `solve` it would be: `x = np.linalg.solve(A_des.T@A_des, A_des.T@b)`. The only other option I found that solves the system faster is: `x = scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A_des, b, atol = 1e-3, btol = 1e-3)` but then the results are not great.

**My function:**

```
def Inverter(GPU, A_des, b):

    if GPU:
        # Migrate b to torch
        b= torch.from_numpy(b).to(device).double()
        # Migrate design matrix to GPU
        A_des = torch.from_numpy(A_des).to(device)
        x= torch.linalg.solve(A_des.T@A_des,A_des.T@(b)).cpu()
    else:
        #x= scipy.sparse.coo_array(A_des)
        #x= scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A_des, b)[0]
        #x = scipy.linalg.solve(A_des.T@A_des,A_des.T@(b))
        x= np.linalg.solve(A_des.T@A_des,A_des.T@b)
        

    return x
```

Comment: Maybe some feedback concerning why my question is bad ? Always helps.

Comment: Please add a representative matrix (doesn't need to be full size) and show typical inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: What specifically is "not great" about the sparse linalg routine? Is it not your favourite colour?

Comment: "not great" meaning that at `atol` and `btol` at 1e-3 values found by the sparse solver are very different than linalg's solver.  To reach similar values found by `linalg.solve()` I have to crank down a`atol` and `btol` to 1e-6, aka blowing up computation time by 15 in my case. So yeah, not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Numba library for parallelizing functions on GPU

https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html